# TCP遅延ACK無効化の方法について

Tags: visual-studio

Windows7,Visual Studio2015でソケット通信のサーバー側のプログラミングをしてます。
実行時間を早くするために、TCP遅延ACKを無効化したいです。
ネットにある情報ではレジストリを変更する方法が紹介されてますが、
理由あって、レジストリ変更せずに遅延ACKをなくす方法を探しています。
プログラムの中でソケットオプションでTCP_NODELAYを設定する方法がありましたが、これでは遅延ACKはなくなりませんでした。
TCP_QUICKACKとうのもあるらしいですが、Windwosでは定義されてませんでした。

どなたかいい方法を知ってる方はいらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: 「TCP遅延ACKを無効化」することで「実行時間を早く」できることは確認済みでしょうか？ またどのように`TCP_NODELAY`を設定し、どのような確認方法で「遅延ACKはなくなりませんでした」と判断したのでしょうか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。実行時間を早くできることについては、レジストリを変更する方法で確認してます。TCP_NODELAYの確認については、ソケット通信はboostのasioを使用しているのですが、クライアントからのread()処理の前にno_delayオプションをsocketクラスに設定して実行時間を確認しました。